# Адаптивная верстка на Retina

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, macbook, retina

Проблема в том,что на масbook pro 10 слетает дизайн,а проект горит.Я уже все мозги сломал,читая статьи про ретину .Проблема в том,что у меня мак бука нет,а у заказчика он есть и притензия к тому,что нет адаптива на скрол товаров. ДА я не глупы знаю что нужно умножать на  2 пиксели. И т.д. Подскажите как быть?! Может есть прога на мозилу для того,чтобы получить разрешение маков?!

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно ничего умножать на 2.
Наоборот, устройство само делит на 2 и виртуальный пиксель равен 4 реальным.